# Bootstrap confirmation dialog with yes/no buttons events not working in safari

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, safari

I have this code snippet inside modal code

```
<a class='no-button dialog-button-secondary'   id='confirmDialogStudyPeriodNo' data-dissmiss="modal"   href='javascript:doCancel()'>CANCEL</a>
<a class='yes-button rectangle-button'  id='confirmDialogStudyPeriodYes' data-dissmiss="modal"  href='javascript:doConfirm()'>YES</a>
```

The javascript function `doCanel` and `doConfirm` are not triggered in Safari but Chrome.

I also tried having an event handler on modal hide but no luck. Below code works in Chrome.

```
$('#dialogId').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) { 
    alert('dialog closed');
});
```

Comment: Are there errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @Barmar No errors at all.